# Bind data from SP to textbox thats inside gridview

Tags: asp.net

How do I bind data from a SP to my gridview which all have textboxes for each cell. My asp for is below.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Year">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Year") %>'></asp:TextBox>

                </ItemTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Period">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Period") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: How are you binding your gridview in the code behind?

Comment: I'm not its just a empty gridview with textbox in itemtemplates

Comment: I guess I do not exactly understand your question. What do you mean by SP, Stored Procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Use a SQL datasource: Heres an example of mine. I have my connections in it so you would need to substitue yours.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProjectCISConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ConnectionStrings:ProjectCISConnectionString.ProviderName %>"

<SelectParameters> 
                  <asp:ControlParameter name="Textbox1"  
                          ControlID="txttextbox1" Propertyname="Text"/> 
              </SelectParameters> 
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/database/db-storedprocs-aspnet2-csharp.aspx